# How to create TABs on serenity MVC Framework

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to display the contents of my page in tabs and when I click on the record to display the tabs, I get the error showing in the image below

> (SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: SlickGrid requires a valid container, [object Object] does not exist in the DOM.                                            slick.grid.js (277,17)

I believe there is a missing relationship information or data between the dialog.ts and the grid.ts files.

[image]

This is my grid.ts file code

```
(SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: SlickGrid requires a valid container, [object Object] does not exist in the DOM.                                            slick.grid.js (277,17)
```

and this is my dialog.ts file code

```
namespace BCPpro_AspNetCore.CashCall
{
@Serenity.Decorators.registerClass()
@Serenity.Decorators.responsive()
@Serenity.Decorators.panel()
export class CashCallCalendarsDialog extends Serenity.EntityDialog<CashCallCalendarsRow, any> {
    protected getFormKey() { return CashCallCalendarsForm.formKey; }
    protected getIdProperty() { return CashCallCalendarsRow.idProperty; }
    protected getDialogType() { return CashCallCircularsDialog; }
    protected getLocalTextPrefix() { return CashCallCalendarsRow.localTextPrefix; }
    protected getNameProperty() { return CashCallCalendarsRow.nameProperty; }
    protected getService() { return CashCallCalendarsService.baseUrl; }

    protected form = new CashCallCalendarsForm(this.idPrefix);
    private loadedState: string;

    // Add the tabs
    // CALL CIRCULAR SCHEDULE CALENDAR
    private cashCallCalendarsGrid: CashCallCalendarsGrid;

    constructor()
    {
        super();
        DialogUtils.pendingChangesConfirmation(this.element, () => this.getSaveState() !== this.loadedState);

        // Set the Tab Grid and height of the Grids
        // CALL CIRCULAR SCHEDULE CALENDAR
        this.cashCallCalendarsGrid = new CashCallCalendarsGrid(this.byId('CashCallCalendarsGrid'));
    }

    getSaveState()
    {
        try
        {
            return $.toJSON(this.getSaveEntity());
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    loadResponse(data)
    {
        super.loadResponse(data);
        this.loadedState = this.getSaveState();
    }

    // Load the Tabs and set the tab status (active/disabled)
    loadEntity(entity: CashCallCalendarsRow)
    {
        super.loadEntity(entity);

        // Set each of tabs status depending on the forms status
        //############################################################
        // CALL CIRCULAR SCHEDULE CALENDAR
        Serenity.TabsExtensions.setDisabled(this.tabs, 'CashCallCalendars', this.isNewOrDeleted());
        this.cashCallCalendarsGrid.YearId = entity.YearId;
    }

    protected initEntityDialog(itemType, dialog) {
        super.initEntityDialog(itemType, dialog);
        Serenity.SubDialogHelper.cascade(dialog, this.element.closest('.ui-dialog'));
    }


    getToolbarButtons()
    {
        var buttons = super.getToolbarButtons();


        return buttons;
    }

  }
}
```

I wish to know what could be the missing data causing the error.